# Problems with tensor notation

Tags: notation, tensors

I've got a question for the mathematically more educated for I am a humble engineer having a hard time:

$\kappa = \left( \delta_{ij}-n_in_j\right)\displaystyle\frac{\partial u_i}{\partial xj} - s_d\frac{\partial n_i}{\partial x_i}$

I don't see how this equation returns a scalar value, as it should for the second term obviously reassembles a divergence, which is a scalar and $\kappa$ is expected to be a scalar value as well. The first part of the formula is driving me nuts: for me it would translate into a product of two 3x3 tensors - which would result in a 3x3 tensor as well. Can anyone explain to me, what is the basic idea here?

Hopefully I didn't miss a similar question, but searching for mathematical expressions is not straight forward at all.

Thanks for your time and effort!

Comment: In tensor notation, repeated index often implies an automatically summation of that index. This makes repeated indexes dumb and thus the result of summation a scalar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you believe the term $- s_d\frac{\partial n_i}{\partial x_i}$ is a scalar, then it needs to be a summation over $i$. If so, the other terms are likely to be summations as well, over both $i$ and $j$, and therefore you get scalars as well. It is hard to be more specific without knowing the origin of the formula, but it may be helpful to raise some of the indices to indicate that one is using the [Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation).

Comment: Thank you, I found the formula printed as-is in my book on combustion written by engineers for engineers, and yes, we are sloppy when it comes to notation - resulting in confusion far too often. I know about einsteins summation convention but didn't see it span braces and derivatives at the same time but you must be right it will turn out to be one big summation.